# Ruby to get the value from HTML table which has same elements

Tags: ruby, watir

I have a HTML file code which is shown below:

```
<table id="plans" class="brand-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="domain">Plans</th>
            <th class="basic">Basic</th>
            <th class="plus">Plus</th>
            <th class="prime">Prime</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>            
        <tr class="even">
        <td>
            www.test.com
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="upgrade" type="radio">
           //this span element is hidden
            <span class="plan_status"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="upgrade" value="plus www.test.com" type="radio">
           //this span element is hidden
            <span class="plan_status"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="upgrade" value="prime www.test.com" checked="" type="radio">
            <span class="plan_status">current</span>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to check which plan is the current plan in the page through Ruby Watir. Below is the script:

```
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)

browser.goto('file:///C:/Users/Ashwin/Desktop/new.html')

browser.table(:id, 'plans').tds.each do |table_row|
    if table_row.input(:value, 'plus www.test.com').text =~ /current/i
        p 'current plan status is plus'
    elsif table_row.input(:value, 'prime www.test.com').text =~ /current/i
        p 'current plan status is prime'
    else
        p 'current plan status is basic'
    end
end
```

But I am getting the output as:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:513:in `assert_exists': unable to locate element, using {:value=>"plus www.test.com", :tag_name=>"input"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:86:in `text'
        from C:/Users/Name/Documents/NetBeansProjects/RubyApplication6/lib/new_main15.rb:8:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/element_collection.rb:29:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/element_collection.rb:29:in `each'
        from C:/Users/Name/Documents/NetBeansProjects/RubyApplication6/lib/new_main15.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

But I want the output to be as:

```
current plan status is prime
```

Can anyone please help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking which `td` element has the "current" text, I would suggest checking which radio has the `checked` attribute. This reduces the number of elements you have to worry about interacting with.

You can find the selected radio using:

```
table_row.radios.find(&:set?).value
```

You can then check the value of the radio to see if it starts with the word "plus" or "prime":

```
# Note that we scope to the tbody to ignore the header row.
# Also make sure you do `trs` not `tds` for the rows.
table_rows = browser.table(id: 'plans').tbody.trs

# Iterate through the rows and check the checked radio button
table_rows.each do |table_row|
  case table_row.radios.find(&:set?).value
  when /^plus/
    p 'current plan status is plus'
  when /^prime/
    p 'current plan status is prime'
  else
    p 'current plan status is basic'
  end
end
```

Note that for older versions of Ruby (ie v1.9), you will need to find the selected radio using:

```
table_row.radios.find { |r| r.set? }.value
```

Comment: C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:165:in `check_type': expected one of [String, Regexp], got true:TrueClass (TypeError)

Comment: The error says you're using Watir-Webdriver v0.6.11, which is from 2014. So yes, the above won't work as it requires Watir v6.4 (note that the Watir-Webdriver gem is now just the Watir gem). I will update the answer to include a version that should work for older versions.